# How to get contents of MimeReader into a string in java?

Tags: java, spring, email, mime-message

For SimpleMailMessage you can just do:

```
SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage()
msg.setFrom(..)
msg.setTo(..)
msg.setCc(..)
msg.setSubject(..)
msg.setText(..)

msg.toString()
```

And the result would be :

```
SimpleMailMessage: from=test@email.com; replyTo=null; to=test@email.com; ... text=Test Body;
```

This is a nice way to easily see what the contents of SimpleMailMessage is, but that is when you are sending no attachments. I have a attachment functionality where I use

```
MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
helper.setFrom(from);
helper.setTo(to);
helper.setCc(InternetAddress.parse(cc));
helper.setSubject(subject);
helper.setText(body);
FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(attachmentPath);
helper.addAttachment(fileName, file);
```

But when doing `helper.toString()` or `message.toString()`, it only returns a java class literal.

Is there a nice way of sort of showing the contents of the MimeMessage in a string format like the SimpleMailMessage?

Answer (score 1):

One option I can think about is using ObjectMapper from Jackson to convert the object to JSON and print it, like this:

```
MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
helper.setFrom(from);
helper.setTo(to);
helper.setCc(InternetAddress.parse(cc));
helper.setSubject(subject);
helper.setText(body);
FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(attachmentPath);
helper.addAttachment(fileName, file);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String helperAsJson= mapper.writeValueAsString(helper);
```